# ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that audits two fields when they are updated in a table.
I have tried compiling the PL/SQL, but the following error keeps coming up.

```
ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification
```

Referring to other SO questions they mention using **Declare** or **As** to solve this problem

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AUDIT_TRIGGER
BEFORE UPDATE OF MR_STATE, IS_EXEMPT
ON CX_MR mr
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF UPDATING ('MR_STATE') THEN 
          INSERT INTO CX_AUDIT
          (
          INT_ID,
          FIELD_NAME,
          OLD_VAL,
          NEW_VAL,
          CHANGED_DATE,
          CHANGED_BY
          )
          VALUES
          (
          mr.INTEGRATION_ID,
          'MR_STATE',
          :old.MR_STATE,
          :new.MR_STATE,
          SYSDATE,
          'Trigger'
          );
     END IF;

    IF UPDATING ('IS_EXEMPT') THEN 
          INSERT INTO CX_AUDIT
          (
          INT_ID,
          FIELD_NAME,
          OLD_VAL,
          NEW_VAL,
          CHANGED_DATE,
          CHANGED_BY
          )
          VALUES
          (
          mr.INT_ID,
          'IS_EXEMPT',
          :old.IS_EXEMPT,
          :new.IS_EXEMPT,
          SYSDATE,
          'Multiroom'
          );
     END IF;
END;
```

However I am not sure what I should be declaring or if this is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears to be that you have an extra token "mr" after the table name `CX_MR`.  You cannot alias a table name in a trigger definition.

You then appear to go on to try to use the alias in the body of your trigger.  Once you remove the "mr" token, the header of your trigger should compile but you'll get a compilation error when you are using `mr` in your `INSERT` statements.  I'm not sure that I understand what you are attempting to do there, though...  You seem to be aware of how to use the `:new` and `:old` pseudo-records to get the old and new values.  My guess is that you just want the `:new.int_id` in both `INSERT` statements.  But it is not clear to me whether you are avoiding that construct for some reason and whether you expect `mr.int_id` to be something different.

Comment: In my cx_audit and cx_mr table both primary keys are "Int_Id" , I was wanting to prevent ambiguous column names in the plsql

Comment: @serupticious - I'm not following.  If `int_id` is the primary key in `cx_audit` then you would have to generate it from a sequence for every `INSERT` and it would have no relationship to the `int_id` column in the `cx_mr` table.  That seems unlikely to be correct.  Do you expect `mr.int_id` to be something different than `:new.int_id`?

Comment: Ok it is working now after putting new.int_id instead of just the column name. THanks